# How to convert months to years and months?

Tags: python

How can some number of months, be converted to years and months?

23 months = 1 year and 11 months

tried using such code as

`round(23 / 12, 2) = 1.92`

This doesn't give me the expected answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd presumably want `divmod`:

```
total_months = 23
years, months = divmod(total_months, 12)
print(f"{years} years, {months} months")
# 1 years, 11 months
```

The built-in `divmod(x, y)` function returns a 2-tuple of `(x // y, x % y)` - in other words, *the integer quotient of `x` divided by `y`*, and *the remainder after that division*.

Of course, you can always do the same thing yourself with those operations:

```
total_months = 23
years = total_months // 12
months = total_months % 12
```

Answer (score -4):

In C you would do this like so:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int months = 67;
    int years = 0;
    
    for(months; months>11; months-=12)
    {
        years++;
    }
    
    printf("years : %i\n", years);
    printf("months: %i\n", months);
    
    return 0;
}
```

I guess Python supports also any kind of loop.

Comment: This question is for python, not C